# Native ad from various networks supporting image ad in an android app

Tags: android, admob, mopub

Have integrated admob sdk for Native Advance Ads in an android app.Ads are getting successfully displayed from network, image with "Install" app click to action button works perfectly.

Now have changed option from app to website as shown in screen shot
[image]

And have set 50% impression goal to display ads and rest for in-house ads which are just images.

But whenever the ads gets delivered to the app, there is blank white space as shown in the screen shot.

[image]

Have tried with different image dimensions but the result was same.

Have contacted to admob team but they said it wont be possible for Native ads with "Website" option.

Is there any network provider which supports Native ads with image(web) type format for android app and allows to run our own campaign?

Answer (score 1):

you can add mopub to achieve this click below and read documents to achieve this:

https://www.mopub.com/resources/docs/android-sdk-integration/integrating-native-ads-android/

Comment: The link doesn't specify about the in-house campaign/advertisement

Answer (score 0):

[Adzerk](https://adzerk.com/) seems to be one of the best option available in the market with multiple players as they have many trusted and reputed customers.They are offering their ad server on chargeable basis for almost all available formats of ad's. But is there any open source Native ad server platform?